# pandas remove observations depending on multi-index level value

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a multi-index data frame with levels 'id' and 'year':

```
              value    
id      year           
10      2001   100     
        2002   200         
11      2001   110          
12      2001   200     
        2002   300     
13      2002   210
```

I want to keep the `id`s that have values for both years 2001 and 2002. This means I want to obtain:

```
              value    
id      year           
10      2001   100     
        2002   200         
12      2001   200     
        2002   300
```

I know that `df.loc[df.index.get_level_values('year') == 2002]` works but I cannot extend that to account for both 2001 and 2002. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about use `groupby` and `filter`:

```
df.groupby(level=0).filter(
    lambda df:np.in1d([2001, 2002], df.index.get_level_values(1)).all()
)
```